# OpenCV mask operation, elementwise assignment in c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I'd like to assign each pixel of a mat `matA` to some value according to values of `matB`, my code is a nested for-loop:

```
clock_t begint=clock();
for(size_t i=0; i<depthImg.rows; i++){
    for(size_t j=0; j<depthImg.cols; j++){
        datatype px=depthImg.at<datatype>(i, j);
        if(px==0)
            depthImg.at<datatype>(i, j)=lastDepthImg.at<datatype>(i, j);
    }
}
cout<<"~~~~~~~~time: "<<clock()-begint<<endl;
```

and it costs about 40~70ms for a mat of size 640*480.

I could do this easily in python numpy using fancy indexing:

```
In [18]: b=np.vstack((np.ones(3), np.arange(3)))

In [19]: b
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.]])

In [22]: a=np.vstack((np.arange(3), np.zeros(3)))

In [23]: a=np.tile(a, (320, 160))

In [24]: a.shape
Out[24]: (640, 480)

In [25]: b=np.tile(b, (320, 160))

In [26]: %timeit a[a==0]=b[a==0]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop
```

and this is much faster than my hand writing for-loop.

So is there such operation in opencv c++ api?

Comment: did you compile in optimized release mode? should be quite fast then.

Comment: here is a comparison between different openCV access methods: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv

Answer (score 4):

I am unable to replicate your timing results on my machine Your C++ code runs in under 1ms on my machine. However, whenever you have slow iteration, `at<>()` should be immediately suspect. OpenCV has a [tutorial on iterating through images](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv), which I recommend.

However, for the operation you describe, there is a better way. `Mat::copyTo()` allows masked operations:

```
lastDepthImg.copyTo(depthImg, depthImg == 0);
```

This is both faster (about 2x as fast) and far more readable than your nested-loop solution. In addition, it may benefit from hardware optimizations like SSE.

Comment: `copyTo` is exactly what I need, and it runs only 1~3ms per frame -- tens of times faster!! I'm curious that why it's only 2x as fast on your frame?

Comment: @zhangxaochen I suspect it's partially a timing issue. `clock()` is not guaranteed to have high resolution, so you may be getting imprecise timings.

Answer (score 1):

In your C++ code, at every pixel you are making a function call, and passing in two indices which are getting converted into a flat index doing something like `i*depthImageCols + j`.

My C++ skills are mostly lacking, but using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-begin) as a template, I guess you could try something like, which should get rid of most of that overhead:

```
MatIterator_<datatype> it1 = depthImg.begin<datatype>(),
                       it1_end = depthImg.end<datatype>();
MatConstIterator_<datatype> it2 = lastDepthImg.begin<datatype>();

for(; it1 != it1_end; ++it1, ++it2) {
    if (*it1 == 0) {
        *it1 = *it2;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your hint, but that costs more on my machine (about 150ms). How did you try it?

Comment: Your timings seem unlikely at best: you should not be seeing orders of magnitude differences between any of these methods, see e.g. [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/38/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-access-cvmat/). Could it be that you are not computing time properly? [`clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) measures time in _clock ticks_, so the right way to convert that to msec would be `(clock() - begint) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC`

Comment: I see the same trend on the timings. -O3 with GCC 4.8.2 gives 5-12ms for every opencv method i've tried. numpy gives 1-2ms.

Comment: @Jaime `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is 1000 on my machine. Anyway, it's clearly slowing down, and even if `clock()-begint` is not *msec*, it's a measure of time.

Comment: @Jaime Sadly, there is an order-of-magnitude difference between using iterators and other methods. I concur that `clock()` may not be the best time measurement. Using a high-resolution timer would be better.